# Navigating history?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I would like to know how I could traverse back my navigating history.
I remembered an old question I did not have an answer to, but I just discovered an answer about it and I cannot find it again.

Is there any feature similar to the history in Google Chrome, to explore recently visited questions?

Comment: it could be stored in your browser's history feature (depending on your clean up settings etc).

Comment: To answer your discussion question, no it doesn't exist.  As for your feature request to add it, see the possible duplicate.  It has been proposed a number of times before, but so far, it has not been implemented.  The common explanation is your browser tracks your history much better than they can so they don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: In the future, you can mark it as "favorite", so that you can search it among your favorites. I always do and now I start to have a problem because I have way too many :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add your user id to the search then you look only in your posts. Try

```
user:1287856 hasaccepted:no other_keyword [some_tag]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should precise that the question was not mine, and I did not participated, I just looked at it.

Comment: You can view your activity tab. There will be an entry for it if you did something on the question: vote, comment, ...